# What is meant by "charge separation" for resonance structures?

Tags: definitions

I'm confused about the definition of "charge separation" in the context of resonance structures. One of the rules of stability of resonance structure is "the structure with least separation of formal charge is more stable". Does "separation" in this context mean the distance between two charges or does it refer to the difference in the magnitude of two charges? Or it does it mean something entirely different?

And I have searched this site and others for an explanation but there were no clear explanations on what it was or of what it implies in a resonance structure.

Comment: or this one https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87491/charge-separation-and-stability-in-resonating-structures/140022

Comment: I had already seen the first link before I posted my question which did not really help me understand but after visiting the second link i feel like now I have understood to some extent the meaning of charge separation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The good old googling *site:chemistry.stackexchange.com charge separation resonance*

Comment: Simple classic electrostatic should help. I would say that if there must be formal charge separation, then the less unstable limiting form is that whit minimal distance between them, ie minimal "formal electrical dipole". So you have to look for what minimise separation, both for a formal physical distance as well as the overall amount of separated formal charges.